# ExtJS how to set button css by using pressedCls config

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I want to change color when button is pressed. 
I tried to use pressedCls config but it didn't work.
How to fix the problem or is there another way to set css when button is pressed?
Thanks a lot!

Javascript:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
      text: 'Click me',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      cls: 'my-btn',
      pressedCls: 'my-btn-pressed'
});
```

CSS:

```
.my-btn {
    background: Black
}

.my-btn-pressed {
    background: Red;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pdo)

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Hi DrakeES, my version is 5.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I think this is a bug, for 4 ext you just can add "x-"-prefix for your pressedCls.
But for extjs 5 you must use !important directive in your css attribute. Look at this:</s>

**Edited**
Thanks for [@Digigizmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238344/digigizmo)
For ExtJs 5 you need to use correct element selector. For 4 version and earlier just add "x-" prefix for css attribute.

```
.my-btn.x-btn.x-btn-pressed  {
    background: Red;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pe0)

For ExtJs 4 and earlier

```
.x-my-btn-pressed {
    background: Red;
}
```

For ExtJs 5 (wrong way, use correct selector above)

```
.x-btn-pressed.my-btn {
    background: Red !important;
}
```

Comment: There's no bug, this is simply a result of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) - there's plenty of articles detailing how this is calculated and best practice approaches to managing it however in short, you should avoid `!important` - in most cases there's a more qualified selector rule you can use to target an element.  In the ExtJS5 case, [`.my-btn.x-btn.x-btn-pressed`](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pef) for example.

Comment: @Digigizmo, oh thanks, i suspected that is a stupid way(!import using) and tried a lot of selectors, for example .my-btn-pressed.x-btn.x-btn-pressed(this style i see in dev tools on button pressing) - but they did't work. Write this, i will upvote your answer.

Comment: Thank you Igor and Digigizmo. It's useful!